# Setting Binding in code to Text property on TextBox WPF not working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I Have the following XAML in UserControl:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="spContainer">
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbLabelBefore" MinWidth="50" Text="{Binding LabelBefore}"></TextBlock>
    <TextBox Name="txtKey" MinWidth="120"></TextBox>
    <TextBlock Name="tbValue" MinWidth="50"></TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

Next I want to set binding dynamically to Text property on the TextBox-txtKey **from proxy class**.

I Do the following:

```
MDLookup lok = SelectedObject as MDLookup;

string bnd = "Model."+ lok.Name +".Value";            
Binding binding = new Binding(bnd);
binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
//binding.ValidatesOnDataErrors = true;
//binding.NotifyOnValidationError = true;
binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
lok.TxtKey.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
```

Here lok is instance of my user control. And TxtKey is Property in my UserControl of type TextBox that returns the txtKey element:

```
[XmlIgnore]
[Browsable(false)]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
public TextBox TxtKey
{
    get { return this.txtKey; }
    set { this.txtKey = value; }
}
```

If I put:

```
lok.TxtKey.Text = "Some Text"
```

This works.
Also this code for setting binding works in my constructor of my user control. But here doesn't. Any idea why?

Additional: I have ovverided ShouldSerializeContent

```
public override bool ShouldSerializeContent()
{
    return false;
}
```

> The point is I serialize xaml from multiple controls in databasebase and afterwards dynamically load and set DataContext.

Comment: `string bnd = "Model.+ lok.Name +.Value"; ` This is incorrect syntax for binding. What are you actually trying to bind to? Your question is unclear.

Comment: that is binding path, it can be any string. That is not the problem. And it is correct syntax I just forgot the quotes:
string bnd = "Model."+ lok.Name +".Value";

My DataContext has dynamic property Model and in it's collection I have model named dynamically lok.Name and property Value, so the path is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `TxtKey` is the name of a `TextBox` inside your `UserControl`, then you are having problems because you cannot access elements that are inside controls from other controls. Although you *can* access named controls from *inside* the `UserControl` that they were defined in, this does *not* mean that they are publicly available from outside the control.

If `TxtKey` is a `DependencyProperty` of type `UserControl`, then you will find that the `UserControl` class does *not* have a `Text` property in it and so you will still not be able to bind to it. I cannot answer further without you providing further information. In these cases listed above, you *should* have received some sort of compilation or binding error... check your Output window in Visual Studio for errors.

---

UPDATE >>>

In order to achieve what you want, you need to define a `DependencyProperty` in your `UserControl`. I won't show you how to do that here as there are millions of online examples... let's say you name it `Text`. Change the XAML in your `UserControl` to this:

```
<TextBox Name="txtKey" MinWidth="120" Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
    AncestorType={x:Type YourPrefix:YourUserControl}}}" />
```

Then you will have a publicly available property to data bind to or set externally that will update the `TextBox.Text` value:

```
<YourPrefix:YourUserControl Text="{Binding DataBoundTextPropertyOutsideControl}" />
```

Or:

```
<YourPrefix:YourUserControl Text="Plain text string" />
```

Or in code:

```
YourUserControl yourUserControl = new YourUserControl();
yourUserControl.Text = "Plain text string";
```

Or:

```
...
yourUserControl.SetBinding(YourUserControl.TextProperty, binding);
```

Comment: I Updated the content of the question. The problem is that I can access lok.TxtKey.Text, but I cannot set binding to it(from outside the control itself).